# ELF program header virtual address and file offset

Tags: linux, gcc, binary, elf

I know the relationship between the two:

> virtual address **mod** page alignment == file offset **mod** page alignment

But can someone tell me in which direction are these two numbers computed?

Is virtual address computed from file offset according to the relationship above, or vice versa?

### Update

Here is some more detail: when the linker writes the ELF file header, it sets the virtual address and file offset of the program headers.(segments)

For example there's the output of `readelf -l someELFfile`:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x8048094
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x00154 0x00154 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x000154 0x08049154 0x08049154 0x00004 0x00004 RW  0x1000
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x10
```

We can see 2 LOAD segments.

The virtual address of the first LOAD ends at 0x8048154, while the second LOAD starts at 0x8049154.

In the ELF file, the second LOAD is right behind the first LOAD with file offset 0x00154, however when this ELF is loaded into memory it starts at 0x1000 bytes after the end of the first LOAD segment.

But, why? If we have to consider memory page alignment, why doesn't the second LOAD segment starts at 0x80489000? Why does it start at 0x1000 bytes AFTER THE END of the first LOAD segment?

I know the virtual address of the second LOAD satisfies the relationship:

> virtual address **mod** page alignment == file offset **mod** page alignment

But I don't know why this relationship must be satisfied.

Comment: not quite understand the question here. eventually it has to read the content of the file so i suppose it is from virtual addr to file offset. and you can play around with an elf file and dump its content with readelf/objdump/dd etc

Comment: "in which direction are these two numbers computed" -- computed by whom?

Comment: Computed by the linker when it writes the header, presumably

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why does it start at 0x1000 bytes AFTER THE END of the first LOAD segment?

If it didn't, it would have to start at `0x08048154`, but it can't: the two `LOAD` segments have different *flags* specified for their mapping (the first is mapped with `PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC`, the second with `PROT_READ|PROTO_WRITE`. Protections (being part of the page table) can only apply to *whole* pages, not parts of a page. Therefore, the mappings with different protections *must* belong to different pages.

> virtual address mod page alignment == file offset mod page alignment
>   But I don't know why this relationship must be satisfied.

The `LOAD` segments are directly `mmap`ed from file. The actual mapping of the second `LOAD` segment performed for your example will look something like this (you can run your program under `strace` and *see* that it does):

```
mmap(0x08049000, 0x158, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, $fd, 0)
```

If you try to make the virtual address or the offset non-page-aligned, `mmap` will fail with `EINVAL`. The only way to make file data to appear in virtual memory at desired address it to make  `VirtAddr` congruent to `Offset` modulo `Align`, and that is exactly what the static linker does.

Note that for such a small first `LOAD` segment, the *entire* first segment also appears at the beginning of the *second* mapping (with the wrong protections). But the program is not supposed to access anything in the `[0x08049000,0x08049154)` range. In general, it is almost always the case that there is some "junk" before the start of *actual data* in the second `LOAD` segment (unless you get really lucky and the first `LOAD` segment ends on a page boundary).

See also [mmap man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

Answer (score 0):

> virtual address mod page alignment == file offset mod page alignment
> But can someone tell me in which direction are these two numbers computed?

I believe the virtual address is deliberately setup this way to follow the file offset. Files themselves should be compact and can therefore save disk space, so all segment are stored right next to each other, with their boundary recorded in the ELF header.

> virtual address mod page alignment == file offset mod page alignment
> But I don't know why this relationship must be satisfied.

It needs **not** to, the second segment here can be mapped to 0x08049000 without any problem. As long as the segments with different flags be mapped to different virtual pages, everything is fine. But the OS has to allocate yet another physical page (4 KB usually) for the mapping and copy the 4 byte at file offset 0x154 to the start of the page, when loading the resulted ELF executable, which is kind of wasteful.

If the relationship is satisfied, however, the OS can allocate just one single physical page and copy the whole 0x158 (0x154 + 0x4) byte of the file to the page, and map the physical page both to 0x08048000 and 0x08049000 with different flags. This saves physical memory, and makes virtual memory techniques like demand-paging to be applied more easily.