# Trying to generate the smallest ELF file possible in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, elf

What's wrong with my code to generate the smallest possible ELF file?
It runs but produces a segfault and since this is program startup -- I can't seem to debug it.

The program code should be doing the equivalent of doing the exit syscall which I cribbed from [this excellent blog post](https://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <elf.h>

const char* programCode =
    "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00"         // mov    eax, 0x1
    "\xbb\x2a\x00\x00\x00"         // mov    ebx, 0x2a
    "\xcd\x80";                    // int    0x80

int main() {
    // ELF header
    Elf64_Ehdr elfHeader = {
        .e_ident = {
            ELFMAG0, ELFMAG1, ELFMAG2, ELFMAG3,
            ELFCLASS64, ELFDATA2LSB, EV_CURRENT,
            ELFOSABI_NONE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        },
        .e_type = ET_EXEC,
        .e_machine = EM_X86_64,
        .e_version = EV_CURRENT,
        .e_entry = 0x401000,
        .e_phoff = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr),
        .e_shoff = 0,
        .e_flags = 0,
        .e_ehsize = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr),
        .e_phentsize = sizeof(Elf64_Phdr),
        .e_phnum = 1,
        .e_shentsize = 0,
        .e_shnum = 0,
        .e_shstrndx = 0
    };

    // Program header
    Elf64_Phdr programHeader = {
        .p_type = PT_LOAD,
        .p_flags = PF_R | PF_X,
        .p_offset = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr) + sizeof(Elf64_Phdr),
        .p_vaddr = 0x401000,
        .p_paddr = 0,
        .p_filesz = sizeof(programCode),
        .p_memsz = sizeof(programCode),
        .p_align = 0x1000
    };

    // Create and write the ELF file
    int fd = open("minimal.elf", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    ssize_t written = write(fd, &elfHeader, sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr));
    if (written == -1) {
        perror("write");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    written = write(fd, &programHeader, sizeof(Elf64_Phdr));
    if (written == -1) {
        perror("write");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    written = write(fd, programCode, sizeof(programCode));
    if (written == -1) {
        perror("write");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html is 32-bit code.  Are you perhaps running this on a system that doesn't support the 32-bit `int 0x80` system-call ABI, like WSL1?  Is that's the problem, use `mov eax, 231` / `syscall` (`exit_group`) or for smaller code_size `push 60` / `pop rax` / `syscall` (`_exit` aka `pthread_exit`).

Comment: I just tested on a real Linux system, and that's not the problem.  `strace ./minimal.elf` shows `execve("./minimal.elf", ["./minimal.elf"], 0x7ffe30913d20 /* 59 vars */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)` `+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++`.  So it's not getting to the point of executing the machine code; it doesn't like the ELF headers.  `readelf -a` doesn't say anything obvious, although I notice the `0x401000` virt addr has a different alignment than the file offset (0x78), and that "align" is specified as 0x1000.  I'd expect you'd need `0x401078` so the kernel can mmap the executable.

Comment: FASM makes tiny ELF executables on its own if you use `format ELF64 executable`.  `readelf -a` on that shows it uses offset=0, virtaddr = 0x0000000000400000. entry point = 0x400078.

Comment: Near duplicate of [ELF program header virtual address and file offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42599558) but that doesn't suggest the solution of using offset=0.  Also [Why ELF's vaddr is not page aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72414574) describes the requirement that `.p_vaddr - .p_offset` must be page-aligned.

Comment: Ty for your comments. I think I had some wonky sizes -- I didn't know the first LOAD segment should be the ELF header itself. I submitted a working code.

Comment: It doesn't have to include the ELF header; you could equally well have `.p_offset = 0x78` and `.p_vaddr = 0x400078`, with entry point `0x400078`.  The ELF header will end up in memory earlier in the page than the virtual address of the segment, though, but that's inevitable unless you pad your executable so the code starts at a file offset that's a multiple of 4K.  (Like modern binutils `ld` does to minimize stray bytes kicking around in executable pages as possible Spectre / ROP gadgets.  [Minimal binary size now 10x larger after linking than 2 years ago?](//stackoverflow.com/q/65037919))

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working C code:

```
#include <elf.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cstdio>

/**
 * This is the program code that will be written to the ELF file.
 * All it does is call the exit system call with the value 42.
 */
const uint8_t programCode[] = {
    0xb8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // mov    eax, 0x1
    0xbb, 0x2a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // mov    ebx, 0x2a
    0xcd, 0x80};                   // int    0x80
/**
 * This function creates the smallest possible ELF executable file for Linux.
 * It is based on the excellent blog post
 * https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html which
 * accomplishes the same thing except via assembly.
 *
 * Shout-out to GPT4 which also helped write this file.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  // ELF header
  Elf64_Ehdr elfHeader = {
      .e_ident =
          {
              ELFMAG0, ELFMAG1, ELFMAG2,
              ELFMAG3,  // Magic number identifying ELF file format
              ELFCLASS64, ELFDATA2LSB,
              EV_CURRENT,  // ELF class, data encoding, and version
              ELFOSABI_NONE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0  // OS-specific identification (none in this case)
          },
      .e_type = ET_EXEC,        // Executable file type
      .e_machine = EM_X86_64,   // Target machine architecture
      .e_version = EV_CURRENT,  // ELF version
      // x86-64 virtual address entry point is set to 0x400000
      // by ld. Let's use the same value here just to mimic it.
      // We also offset the ELF header and program header table as the machine
      // code will be written to the file after them.
      .e_entry = 0x400000 + sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr) + sizeof(Elf64_Phdr),
      .e_phoff = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr),  // Offset of the program header table
      .e_shoff = 0,  // Offset of the section header table (none in this case)
      .e_flags = 0,  // Processor-specific flags
      .e_ehsize = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr),     // Size of ELF header
      .e_phentsize = sizeof(Elf64_Phdr),  // Size of program header entry
      .e_phnum = 1,                       // Number of program header entries
      .e_shentsize = 0,  // Size of section header entry (none in this case)
      .e_shnum = 0,      // Number of section header entries (none in this case)
      .e_shstrndx = 0  // Index of section header entry for section name strings
                       // (none in this case)
  };

  // Program header
  Elf64_Phdr programHeader = {
      .p_type = PT_LOAD,  // Type of the program header entry (loadable segment)
      .p_flags = PF_R | PF_X,  // Segment flags (readable and executable)
      .p_offset = 0,           // Offset of the segment in the file
      // Virtual address at which the segment should be loaded in memory
      // We set it to 0x400000 to mimic ld.
      .p_vaddr = 0x400000,
      // Physical address at which the segment should be loaded. We don't
      // care about physical addresses so we set it to 0.
      .p_paddr = 0,
      // This field represents the size of the segment in the file. It indicates
      // the number of bytes occupied by the segment's data within the ELF file
      // itself. The p_filesz field includes any padding or alignment bytes, as
      // well as the actual data of the segment.
      .p_filesz = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr) + sizeof(Elf64_Phdr) + sizeof(programCode),
      // This field represents the size of the segment in memory. It indicates
      // the total memory required by the segment when loaded into memory during
      // program execution. The p_memsz field encompasses the entire space
      // allocated for the segment in memory, including any padding, alignment,
      // or additional memory allocated for uninitialized portions.
      // Typically, p_filesz will be less than or equal to p_memsz, as p_filesz
      // represents the actual occupied size of the segment in the file, while
      // p_memsz represents the size needed in memory to accommodate the
      // segment's data.
      .p_memsz = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr) + sizeof(Elf64_Phdr) + sizeof(programCode),
      //  This field represents the alignment requirements for the segment. It
      //  specifies the minimum alignment, in bytes, that the segment's data
      //  should adhere to when loaded into memory.
      // If you need to indicate that no specific alignment requirement is
      // necessary for a segment, it is common to set p_align to 1. This means
      // that the segment's data does not have any strict alignment requirements
      // and can be loaded at any address.
      .p_align = 1};

  // Create and write the ELF file
  int fd =
      open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR);
  if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open");
    return 1;
  }

  // Write ELF header to the file
  ssize_t written = write(fd, &elfHeader, sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr));
  if (written == -1) {
    perror("write");
    close(fd);
    return 1;
  }
  // Write program header to the file
  written = write(fd, &programHeader, sizeof(Elf64_Phdr));
  if (written == -1) {
    perror("write");
    close(fd);
    return 1;
  }
  // Write program code to the file
  written = write(fd, programCode, sizeof(programCode));
  if (written == -1) {
    perror("write");
    close(fd);
    return 1;
  }

  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

I've commented it above to help explain how I got to my rationale.
You can also find the code in [my repository](https://github.com/fzakaria/elf2sql/blob/893d8209b8dbbe1ac398b953f822c156cfbb21a8/src/examples/teensy.cc)

Comment: It would be good if your answer described what changes you made, e.g. that `.p_vaddr - .p_offset` had to be page aligned so the kernel could mmap the executable.

Comment: It was late last night -- I'm going to edit this with a commented version for the code with all the learnings 

Comment: Your comments don't mention the alignment problem your original version had.  And they're overly verbose for p_filesz, p_memsz and p_align, like you copy/pasted some detailed documentation into your source code.  Does `.p_align = 1` let you have `(p_vaddr - p_offset) % 4096 != 0`?  I don't think so, and if not, that's way too much attention to it and no attention to the actual important thing you were fixing.